# Windows XP x64, VirtualBox 3.0.10, Karmic Koala blue screen

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, ubuntu-9.10, virtualbox

Here's my setup:

- Widows XP x64
- VirtualBox 3.0.10
- Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala

Installation of VirtualBox works, and so does installation of Karmic onto a new virtual machine. When I try to boot into the VM, however, my host system crashes blue screen style.

- Windows XP x64 + VirtualBox 2.2.4 + Ubuntu 9.04 works.
- Windows XP x64 + VirtualBox 2.2.4 + Ubuntu 9.10 works, but the Guest Additions fail to install.

Does anybody have any experience with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely is to do with Virtual Box itself and not related directly to running Ubuntu.

First thing to try is [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) which should be able to diagnose previous blue screens and tell you what the problem is.

If it is driver related, you would want to take a look for updates and if you cannot find one, try disabling in Virtualbox the device that will tie in with that driver if possible (For example, in a previous version, I discovered a bug with the Network card - whilst annoying, disabling the NIC stopped blue screens).

If it is unknown, you may want to do some general diagnosing starting with a [Memory checker](http://memtest.org).

Comment: Thanks. I used the BlueScreenView app, and there was some evidence it was audio related. I disabled audio in the VM, and everything works now. I now have Ubuntu 9.10 installed in VirtualBox 3.0.10 with Guest Additions on a Windows XP x64 host.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the following settings:

- Host: Windows XP pro 64 bit, SP2
- Guest: Ubuntu 9.10
- Virtual Box 3.0.12

Disabling audio worked for me too.

Comment: I was hoping 3.0.12 would fix it, but I see that it won't. Thanks for saving me the frustration! ;)